# "Vuforia Core Samples", but there is no Word-list file

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

i'm trying to start using Text recognition in my unity project, i've download the asset "Vuforia Core Samples", but there is no Word-list file.
is there anyway to create my own word-list file, or download one?

Answer (score 0):

English word list is available on Vuforia website. If you downloaded Vuforia Core Samples from Unity Asset Store than you probably didn't get it in the package. See This-- you can download from here https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Text-Recognition-Guide

Once you download wordlist, you would need to unzip the file and put it in the asset folder. Please check this for more info-https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/standard-wordlist-download

[image: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Text-Recognition-Guide]